# PHP - Sending Mail is not working

Tags: php, email

I've seen some other posts on this, and I'm learning from a book right now. I've followed what the book said and I'm not understanding what I'm missing.

I tried not to make it a double post, but the codes are quite different from the ones I read on stackoverflow so here I go. I hope someone can help me. I am a complete beginner.

My `Basic.php` has this script

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="POST">
<p><strong>Name:</strong><br />
<input type="text" size="25" name="name" /></p>
<p><strong>E-Mail Address:</strong><br />
<input type="text" size="25" name="email" /></p>
<p><strong>Message:</strong><br />
<textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="send" /></p>
</form>
```

My `sendmail.php` has this script.

```
echo "<p>Thank you, <b>" . $_POST['name'] . "</b>, for your message!</p>";
echo "<p>Your e-mail address is: <b>" . $_POST['email'] . "</b>. </p>";
echo "<p>Your message was: <br/>";
echo $_POST['message']."</p>";
//start building the mail string
$msg = "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "\n";
$msg .= "E-mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
$msg .= "Message: " . $_POST['message'] . "\n";
//set up the mail
$recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Form Submission Results";
$mailheaders = "From: me \n";
$mailheaders .= "Reply To " . $_POST['email'];
//send the mail
mail($recipient, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);
```

And here is my `php.ini` that I've changed (this part I have no clue about).

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 465
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = myemail@gmail.com
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get. Thank you!

BTW I'm getting the following error:
 Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 wx2sm302658igb.4 - gsmtp in C:\wamp\www\sam\sendmail.php on line 24

Comment: Is there any error or what?

Comment: Yes I'm getting the following error:

Comment: Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 wx2sm302658igb.4 - gsmtp in C:\wamp\www\sam\sendmail.php on line 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PHP` code looks fine but probably you won't be able to send e-mail using `PHP's` core `mail` function, via `gmail`'s `SMTP` server. Have a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028428/using-core-php-mail-to-send-via-gmail-smtp?lq=1) as it could help you.