# PHP - Send HTML and plain Text email doesn't work in Gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, boundary

Could you explane me what is wrong in this simple code?
It doesn't work with Gmail but yes with some other clients.

```
$boundary = md5( uniqid() . microtime() );
$to      =  $user;
$headers[] = 'From: my@email.com';
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';   
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="'.$boundary.'"\r\n';
$subject = "The subject";
$message = "--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n"; 
$message .= 'Simple Text Message line 1\r\nline 2\r\nline 3';
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "<h1>html message!</h1>";
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers))
```

In Gmail I get something like this:

```
--05fd97038918d12debb49153b3ad67a5
Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Simple Text Message line 1\r\nline 2\r\nline 3

--05fd97038918d12debb49153b3ad67a5
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<h1>html message!</h1>

--05fd97038918d12debb49153b3ad67a5--
```

Comment: Luca, have you tried the suggestion/solution found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page ?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but i prefer don't use external libraries. Can i do the same without libraries?

Comment: What is your reasoning behind not using external libraries?

Comment: Regardless, did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028428/using-core-php-mail-to-send-via-gmail-smtp

Comment: Specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24103112/7019742

Comment: I don't understand: why i can't send a mail html/simple text to Gmail with php mail() but the email only html and only simple text yes? nonsense

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the responses! I'll see your link searching a solution